# "Database X does not exist." when accessing DB after CreateTemporaryInstance method of SQLLocalDbAPI - How to fix it?

Tags: c#, mstest, localdb

I am setting up some integration tests which use temporary DB instances; and the API that creates these temporary instances on-the-fly seems to go finely (i.e. no exceptions). 
However, when I try to use these instances an exceptions is thrown (i.e. "Database 'X' does not exist.", where X is current temporary instance name). What am I missing?

I am currently using MSTest as test environment, SQLLocalDB as "DBMS", and  MartinCostello.SQLLocalDB as library to manage SQLLocalDB.

```cs
using (var localDB = new SqlLocalDbApi(OutputHelper.ToLoggerFactory()))
{
  using (TemporarySqlLocalDbInstance instance = localDB.CreateTemporaryInstance(deleteFiles: true))
  {
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(instance.ConnectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();

      using (var command = new SqlCommand("CommandToExecute", connection))
      {
        try
        {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"An exception was thrown: {ex.Message}");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that the instance would be created, but when the SQL command executes, it throws an exception:

> Database '44a44154-5ad8-4c7f-89b1-d5635504fdbe' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

If I check the DB existence in visual studio "SQL Server Object Explorer", I see localdb, but I do not see the temporary instance.

Anyone can point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: SQL Server uses an MDF file for the database.  The database has to be attached to the server except if the connection string contains an attach statement clause.  Once the database becomes attached to the SQL Server the server owns the mdf file and depending on the credentials in the server access to the database is limited to the access list.  When the connection string contains the attach clause then the MDF file has to be accessible to the user.  So if the MDF is on a remote machine or in another user account you cannot have an attach if you do not have access to the file.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, your comment pointed me in the right direction!
I discovered that I was using the instance as DB as well; figured out my mistake and fixed it, I had some "access denied" issues. Fortunately, after some googling I solved those issues by specifying a valid destination via CREATE DATABASE FILENAME param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @jdweng comment, I figured out that I was using the instance name as DB name as well and without creating it. Hence, execute the command to create a new DB was enough to solve my issue.
For example, `CREATE DATABASE [44a44154-5ad8-4c7f-89b1-d5635504fdbe] ...`

After that, I had some issues on path permissions. However, some googling allowed me to discover that I could specify a valid-access file path for the MDF and LDF files.

Now, everything works like a charm!